# actionListener method not working

Tags: jsf

I have a form with several fields and command button.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <p:commandButton value="#{messages.SaveButton}"
            actionListener="#{groupBean.save()}" styleClass="btn"
            update=":dlg :groupRegistrationForm"
            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dialogWidget.show()" />
        <br /> <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

And everything works fine when I deploy it on my local jboss server v 7.1.1.

However, when I deploy it on the test environment (same jboss version) the actionListener method does not get called.

I am struggling to figure out what the problem is since this is one of several similar funcionalities and I only have problem with this one.

The server starts without errors and the other pages action methods get called on both environments.

I've tried also with action="#{groupBean.save()}"

Comment: Any Javascript errors in the console ? Watch the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, see what's going on with the response...

Comment: Thanks, indeed the reason was a js error that was breaking the form!